# Get step id in Jenkins Pipeline for linking to BlueOcean or Pipeline Steps view (flowGraphTable)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

Given a Jenkins pipeline that runs a series of steps, some within `parallel` blocks, is there any way to obtain *within the pipeline* the Flow id of a given step or the most recent step?

What's a Flow ID? If you look at a Run of your Pipeline job you can see a "Pipeline Steps" link that points to `flowGraphTable/`. There you have links to specific job steps like `execution/node/113/`. These seem to represent a [`FlowNode`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/graph/FlowNode.html).

Is there any way to get these IDs from within the pipeline, for generating links etc?

In particular I want to get a link to the sub-Flow for my parallel branches so I can link to the BlueOcean views of them. (The builtin Jenkins view is useless because it doesn't show a subtree).

I can see that the BlueOcean links correspond to the /execution/ links, they have the same id value. If my pipeline branch is `myjob/9/execution/node/78/` then on blueocean it'll be `jobname/9/pipeline/78`.

But how do I get that ID if I want to use the build summary plugin or similar to generate the links and add them to the build results page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In particular I want to get a link to the sub-Flow for my parallel
> branches so I can link to the BlueOcean views of them.

You can get the *head* flow node (most recent step) of the *current* thread (aka branch) using `CpsThread.current().head.get()`. Then you can use `FlowNode.iterateEnclosingBlocks()` to find the parent branch by checking whether a block start node contains an instance of `ThreadNameAction`.

Complete pipeline example:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.LabelAction
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ThreadNameAction

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage("parallel start"){
            parallel {
                stage("A"){
                    steps{
                        showCurrentBranchUrls()
                        echo "Another step"
                    }
                }
                stage("B"){
                    steps{
                        echo "Some stuff"
                        showCurrentBranchUrls()
                        echo "More stuff"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void showCurrentBranchUrls() {
    // Get the most recent FlowNode of current branch
    FlowNode headNode = CpsThread.current().head.get()
    
    // Find the nearest parent branch
    FlowNode branchNode = getFlowNodeOfParentBranch( headNode )
    if( branchNode ) {
        // Print some useful URLs based on branchNode
        echo "Blue Ocean branch view: ${JENKINS_URL}blue/organizations/jenkins/${JOB_NAME}/detail/${JOB_BASE_NAME}/${BUILD_ID}/pipeline/${branchNode.id}"
        echo "Blue Ocean branch log: ${JENKINS_URL}blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/${JOB_NAME}/runs/${BUILD_ID}/nodes/${branchNode.id}/log"
        echo "Pipeline steps: ${JENKINS_URL}${branchNode.url}"
    }
}

// Get FlowNode of parent branch
@NonCPS
FlowNode getFlowNodeOfParentBranch( FlowNode node ) {
    node.iterateEnclosingBlocks().find{ enclosing ->
        enclosing != null && 
        enclosing.getAction( LabelAction.class ) != null && 
        enclosing.getAction( ThreadNameAction.class ) != null
    }
}
```

In a sandboxed pipeline script the code may trigger some security errors, so I recommend to put it into a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) which doesn't have such restrictions.

---

In case you want to find the node ID of *another* branch instead of the current branch, the class [`PipelineNodeGraphVisitor`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/blueocean-pipeline-api-impl/io/jenkins/blueocean/rest/impl/pipeline/PipelineNodeGraphVisitor.html) comes in handy. There are already [many examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pipelinenodegraphvisitor) on SO, e. g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64156783/7571258) of mine.

---

For further reading, here is a good overview about working with the [Jenkins Flow Graph](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-api-plugin/blob/master/docs/flowgraph.md).

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the a similar use case and managed to find a solution that is working for me. This https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28119 might be an interesting read on the issue. It eventually pointed me in a good direction.

Besides the Pipeline and Pipeline Stage View Plugin, I had to install the HTTP Request Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin) and the Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin (for parsing JSON, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin) on our Jenkins server. I am not sure which other plugins might be required.

Here is my working example, only missing the stages being evaluated:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def responseRun = httpRequest(
                        //consoleLogResponseBody: true,
                        contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                        httpMode: 'GET',
                        url: BUILD_URL + 'wfapi',
                        validResponseCodes: '200'
                    )
                    def runJson = readJSON text: responseRun.getContent()
                    def headNodeUrl = ''
                    runJson.stages.each {
                        if (it.name.toString() == 'Stage node label') {
                            // Found head node: it.id
                            headNodeUrl = BUILD_URL + 'execution/node/' + it.id.toString() + '/'
                        }
                    }
                    def responseNode = httpRequest(
                        contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                        httpMode: 'GET',
                        url: headNodeUrl + 'wfapi',
                        validResponseCodes: '200'
                    )
                    def nodeJson = readJSON text: responseNode.getContent()
                    def execNodeUrl = ''
                    nodeJson.stageFlowNodes.each {
                        if (it.name.toString() == 'Execution node label') {
                            // Found execution node: it.id
                            execNodeUrl = BUILD_URL + 'execution/node/' + it.id.toString() + '/log/'
                        }
                    }
                    echo execNodeUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`BUILD_URL` is a global environment variable, supplied by Jenkins, I assume. In my full script I have a `stage('Stage node label') { ... }` containing a statement `bat label: 'Execution node label', script: ...` whose log URL will be constructed and printed with `echo`.

The result is a URL like `http://myjenkinsserver.org:8080/job/some_folder/job/my_job_name/181/execution/node/50/log/`

I think the use of `each` in my example might not be ideal, since I cannot abort it after the first match. Also I didn't manage to encapsulate the `httpRequest` and `readJSON` into a class method or something because I couldn't figure out the return type of `readJSON`. Any hints are appreciated.

I hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

This gets the workspace link for the enclosing node step.
You can get the Id by using .getId() instead of .url
This works for my case when using node { .... }, but may require some polishing for using in declarative or inside parallel steps.

```
def getNodeWsUrl(flowNode = null) {
    if(!flowNode) {
        flowNode = getContext(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode)
    }
    if(flowNode instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepStartNode && flowNode.typeFunctionName == 'node') {
        // Could also check flowNode.typeDisplayFunction == 'Allocate node : Start'
        return "/${flowNode.url}ws/"
    }

    return flowNode.parents.findResult { getNodeWsUrl(it) }
}
```

Comment: wow, that thing is a deep structure, it seems it needs to recurse a couple of dozen times before it hits a usable node

Comment: In fact, I hit recursion limits, so this needs to be done right after a node instruction I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I use some hack. Add to sh step for which I would like get Flow ID some output. Then find in log this string and get Flow ID from log. Where ${e} is index for cycle for make output unique.

```
sh "echo "Run TESTENV=TestEnv_${e}"
```

Then at the end of pipeline, for generate URL, get the Flow ID from logs.
Initial log Index first once.

```
node('master'){
   logIndex=getLogMap()
```

Then in cycle get URL, where e is index in cycle:

```
   stepURL=getURL(logIndex, "Run TESTENV=TestEnv_${e} ")
}
```

Functions which you can put in shared lib:

```
import jenkins.branch.NameMangler
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def keyString = 'Run TESTENV=TestEnv'

def getLogMap() {
  def tokens = "${env.JOB_NAME}".tokenize('/')
  def repo = tokens[tokens.size()-2]
  try {
    def i
    def result=[:]
    exec = """
      set +x
      LOG_FILE="\$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/${repo}/branches/${NameMangler.apply(env.BRANCH_NAME)}/builds/\$BUILD_ID/log"
      LOG_INDEX_FILE="\$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/${repo}/branches/${NameMangler.apply(env.BRANCH_NAME)}/builds/\$BUILD_ID/log-index"
      LOG_LINES=\$(grep --byte-offset --text "${keyString}" "\$LOG_FILE"| sed "s/[^[:print:]\t]//g; s/\\(^[0-9]*:\\).*=\\(.*\\)/\\1 \\2/g; s/'\$//g")
      LOG_INDEX=\$(grep '.* .*' "\$LOG_INDEX_FILE")
      while read -r line ; do
          offset=\$(echo \$line | cut -d ":" -f1)
          str=\$(echo \$line | cut -d " " -f2)
          if [[ "X\$offset" == "X" ]]; then
            echo "Offset if empty in line=\$line"
            continue
          fi
          index=\$(echo "\$LOG_INDEX" | awk '\$1 > '\$offset' { print  prev; exit; } { prev = \$2 }')
          echo "\$str \$index"
      done <<< "\$LOG_LINES" | uniq
      """
    return sh(script: exec, returnStdout: true).trim().tokenize('\n')
  } catch (error) {
    throw (error)
  }
}

def getURL(logIndex, findString) {
  findString=findString.replaceAll(".*=", "")
  resultStr=logIndex.findAll { it.contains(findString) }
  def result=''
  for (s in resultStr){
    i=s.tokenize()
    result = result + "[log|${env.BUILD_URL}execution/node/" + i[1] + '/log/] '
  }
  return result.trim()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of getting Step Id for parallel job you can echo or specify the node name that can work.

Comment: Can that then be used to construct URLs referring to nodes 
 in BlueOcean display of the job, or to the flow graph table / pipeline steps view though? if so, how?