# Getting jenkinsfile parallel branch run status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got multiple parallel branches job, each branch contains numerous stages.

```
def build_jobs = [:]

build_jobs['1'] = {
    stage ('A'){}
    stage ('B'){}
}
        
build_jobs['2'] = {
    stage ('A'){}
    stage ('B'){}
}

build_jobs['3'] = {
    stage ('A'){}
    stage ('B'){}
}
parallel build_jobs
```

Thru the API I can find only separate stage status and whole build status.(using /api/json and /wfapi)
I need a way to reach at the end of each build the branch name and it status.

```
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 1) - status ?
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 2) - status ?
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 3) - status ?
```

Getting status if each stage doesn't support my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the easiest way is to use [`PipelineNodeGraphVisitor`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/blueocean-pipeline-api-impl/io/jenkins/blueocean/rest/impl/pipeline/PipelineNodeGraphVisitor.html) from BlueOcean plugin to query all nodes of type `FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.PARALLEL`. These are the branches.

```groovy
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineNodeGraphVisitor
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper

@NonCPS
List getBranchResults( RunWrapper build ) {

    def visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor( build.rawBuild )
    def branches = visitor.pipelineNodes.findAll{ it.type == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.PARALLEL }
    
    return branches.collect{ branch -> [ 
        id: branch.id, 
        displayName: branch.displayName, 
        result: "${branch.status.result}",
    ]}
}

node {
    def build_jobs = [:]
    
    build_jobs['1'] = {
        stage ('A'){ echo 'Success' }
        stage ('B'){ echo 'Success' }
    }
            
    build_jobs['2'] = {
        stage ('A'){ echo 'Success' }
        stage ('B'){ error 'Error' }
    }
    
    build_jobs['3'] = {
        stage ('A'){ echo 'Success' }
        stage ('B'){ warnError( message: 'Unstable' ){ error 'Error' } }
    }
    
    try {
        parallel build_jobs    
    }
    finally {
        def results = getBranchResults( currentBuild )
        echo "Branch results:\n" + results.join('\n')
    }
}
```

[image: BlueOcean visualization]

Output of last 'echo' (open console log to see it):

```
Branch results:
[id:8, displayName:1, result:SUCCESS]
[id:9, displayName:2, result:FAILURE]
[id:10, displayName:3, result:UNSTABLE]
```

A [similar answer to get stage results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837364/7571258) also lists an alternative to BlueOcean API.