# How to get exact corresponding http Jenkins workspace path?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to email following path after Jenkins build is completed -

`http://<ip>:8080/job/Nightly_Build/51/execution/node/64/ws/`

Using `BUILD_URL` environment variable, I can get path till `http://<ip>:8080/job/Nightly_Build/51`. Remaining path we can hardcode except value `64` in above path which keep changes when I make changes in pipeline code.

I am unable to get that value on the fly.

Can someone explain what is that `64` number in the path and how can it be retrieved using Jenkins environment variable or APIs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get step id in Jenkins Pipeline for linking to BlueOcean or Pipeline Steps view (flowGraphTable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287643/get-step-id-in-jenkins-pipeline-for-linking-to-blueocean-or-pipeline-steps-view)